# how to loop a json object in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

i have this static data:

```
  $scope.data = {
                    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'My First dataset',
                            fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
                            strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                            pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            data: [75, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 84, 64, 120, 132, 87]
                        }

                    ]
                };
```

My problem is: my real data come from the backend heres returned JSON Object :

```
[{"number":2,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères","la_date":1506960648000},{"number":7,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurité Conducteur","la_date":1509542654000},{"number":1,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères","la_date":1512134781000}]
```

I used the for loop , to loop the data:

```
 getIncidentDepartByMonthFromTo.forEach(function(data) {
               // charCtrl.toto.push($filter('monthName')(monthNumber));
                var monthNumber=$filter('date')(data.la_date, "MM");
                //$scope.labelsf.push($filter('monthName')(monthNumber));
                var mun=data.number;
                //$scope.dataf.push(data.number);
                $scope.data = {
                    labels: [monthNumber],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'My First dataset',
                            fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
                            strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                            pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            data: [num]
                        }

                    ]
                };
            });
```

but this loop gives just the last result in the JSON object I mean tis one:

```
{"number":1,"des":"Ceintures De Sécurités Passagères","la_date":1512134781000}
```

How i can get all the data please?? i have to use a push or smonrhing like that??

Answer (score 0):

```
getIncidentDepartByMonthFromTo.forEach(function(data) {

                var monthNumber=$filter('date')(data.la_date, "MM");

                var num = data.number;

                data = {
                    labels: [monthNumber],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'My First dataset',
                            fillColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.2)',
                            strokeColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            pointColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                            pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                            pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',
                            data: [num]
                        }

                    ]
                };
            });
```

you dont have to assign values to $scope.data

Comment: i did actually just i missed that but it doesnt work

Comment: @imsiimsi, why?

Comment: i dont know why? this is my question